# matrix operation that turn a vector into matrix whose row is that vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a vector $v=[a_1,..,a_n]$ and a number $k$, Is there a matrix operation that create the matrix $M$ with $k$ rows where each rows of $M$ is $v$?

Is this correct?
$[1,1,...,1]^T *[a_1,...,a_n]$

Here is a follow up question:

Say we have a vector $v=[a_1,..,a_n]^T$ and a matrix $M \in M_{x \times y}(\mathbf{R})$,

I want to do $(v*row_1of(M)+v*row_2of(M)+...+v*row_xof(M))/x$, Here each of $v*row_iof(M)$ is a matrix and we add all those matrices and then take average of all of its entries. Is there a matrix operation for that?

Comment: Yes, if [1,1,....,1]^T has dimension [k x 1] and v has dimension [1 x n] you get a matrix M with v as rows and dimension [k x n]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let $N = [1, 1, ..., 1]^T$, a $kx1$ matrix with all entries $1$. Then $N \cdot v = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    1 \\
    \vdots \\
    1 
\end{bmatrix} \cdot [a_1, ... a_n]  = \begin{bmatrix}
    a_1, ... a_n  \\
    a_1, ... a_n \\
    \vdots \\
    a_1, ... a_n 
\end{bmatrix}
$